# orphanRemoval being ignored

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink and I have a one to many relationship with the one side annotated with orphanRemoval=true.  When I set the "many" list (quoteItems) to null and attempt a merge followed by a flush against the parent (Quote, the "one" insteance), JPA attempts to update the children, setting the foreign key to null rather than removing the children.  Here is the code:

The "One" class

```
public class Quote implements NamedBean, Serializable {
.
.
.
    // bi-directional many-to-one association to QuoteItem
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quote", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, orphanRemoval=true)
    @XmlElement
    public List<QuoteItem> getQuoteItems() {
        if ((quoteItems == null || quoteItems.size() == 0) && (quoteAsXml != null && quoteAsXml.length() > 0)) {
            // Reconstitute the quoteItems from the quoteAsXml
            QuoteDAO.unpackQuoteItems(this);
        }

        return this.quoteItems;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

The "many" class:

```
public class QuoteItem implements Serializable {
.
.
.
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Quote
    @ManyToOne
    @XmlTransient
    public Quote getQuote() {
        return this.quote;
    }

.
.
.
}
```

The truncated stack dump:

```
.
.
.
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'quote_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: UPDATE quote_item SET QUOTE_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [null, 64]
Query: UpdateObjectQuery(com.millereads.model.quote.QuoteItem@11e6d13)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.updateObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.updateObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:1078)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(UpdateObjectQuery.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitChangedObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4263)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'quote_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2347)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892)
    ... 124 more
```

Persistence code (as it currently stands, with the same complaint)

```
    public Quote update(Quote entity) {
        if (entity.getState() == QuoteState.POIssued) {
            String quoteAsXml = entity.getQuoteAsXml();

            if (quoteAsXml == null || quoteAsXml.length() == 0) {
                // Convert the Quote into XML 
                try {
                    JAXBContext contextObj;

                    contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(Quote.class);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();  
                    marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);  

                    marshallerObj.marshal(entity, outStream);  
                    entity.setQuoteAsXml(outStream.toString());
                } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }  
            }

            // Do not save the quoteItems!              
            entity.getQuoteItems().clear();
        }

        return super.update(entity);
    }
```

Ancestor class' update():

```
    @Override
    public T update(T entity) {
        T result =  manager.merge(entity);
        manager.flush();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing instead of nullifying the collection? It might not matter with an eagerly-loaded relationship, but still worth a try.

Comment: I just attempted it again to verify... it gives the same complaint when I clear() the list instead of setting it to null.

Comment: Please also post your persistence code.

Comment: Are you nulling out the QuoteItem's quote?  There is no reason JPA would set that reference to null otherwise.  Check exactly what you are doing in that transaction as you shouldn't change the QuoteItem if you are going to delete it.

Comment: I've edited the description to include requested code.

Comment: @Chris, I am not presently walking through the QuoteItems and nulling out their back references to the Quote.

Comment: It is xmlTransient. Could you be merging in one that doesn't have the reference set?

Comment: No chance of that.  For that to happen it would have to occur in the body of the try block in the update() method.   entity.setQuoteAsXml(outStream.toString()) is the only method which access to accomplish that, and it is a simple mutator, nothing but an assignment in it.

I had intended remove all the rows beneath the Quote row, but I took a different approach and explored how much of the object graph I could delete from the DB, backing it up to a table that is owned in two directions (by two different tables).  Sufficient for my needs, but I suspect that is an unconsidered situation.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have found a my work around.